# How to list all git branches containing no unique commits

Tags: git

I've found information on showing all branches that contain a given commit.  However, how do I find branches on my remote that are newly created that have no commits against them?

Answer (score 2):

You can see all branches that have no commits not merged, by running `git branch --merged`

This should accomplish what you want. Newly created branches that have no commits are really no different than old branches that have been merged.

Comment: *With --merged, only branches merged into the named commit (i.e. the branches whose tip commits are reachable from the named commit) will be listed.*

Comment: Yeah, that command is my starting point.  However, in our workflow, it's very common for us to have a branch with nothing committed against it (it's how all feature branches start).  I want to separate those branches from branches that have been merged back into develop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me what the question means.

Here is a simple example.  Suppose we draw this graph:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
         \
          o--X    <-- br1, br2
```

`master` points to its tip commit.  Branches `br1` and `br2` both point to their own tip commits, but both commits are commit `X`.  In that sense, at least one of these branch names is redundant.

Now, you said:

> branches on my remote that are newly created

It's easy to find remote-tracking branch names: they're the ones in the `refs/remotes/` namespace.  The ones for the remote named `origin` are in `refs/remotes/origin/`.

"Newly created", however, is not meaningful in Git.  Branch names can be created or destroyed at any time, pointing to any commit.  Given the graph drawn so far, we can add a new `br3` pointing to the commit before `X`.  If we do that on `origin` and then run `git fetch`, we get:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- master
         \
          o       <-- origin/br3
           \
            X     <-- br1, br2
```

This really is the same *commit graph*; I just moved `X` down to a new row so that I had space to fit in the name, `origin/br3`.

That name—`origin/br3`—is, in a sense, redundant with both of our own `br1` and `br2` names, as it does not serve to *retain* any commits we would not already retain.  But it's *different from* any names we have.

The `git branch` options `--contains`, `--merged`, and `--no-merged` (now available in `git for-each-ref` as well, since Git 2.7.0) are merely en-masse tests for "is or is not an ancestor", with some variation on precisely what is tested against what-else.  Going back to this graph but adding more names:

```
...--U--V--Y--Z   <-- master
         \
          W--X    <-- br1, br2
```

the graph tells us that `U` is an ancestor of every other labeled commit, `Y` is an ancestor of `Z`, `W` is an ancestor of `X`, and so on.  `W` is *not* an ancestor of `Y`, however, as commit nodes only link "backwards"—leftwards, in these graph drawings—so `W` goes back to `V`, and `Y` goes back to `V`, but `Y` does not connect to `W` at all.

For these "is an ancestor" tests, a commit is always considered an ancestor of itself.  (That is, these are less-than-or-equal-to, ≤, tests, rather than strictly-less-than.)

Running `git branch --contains <id>` commit means: for each branch name, look up its tip commit.  (That's `Z`, `X`, and then `X` again.)  Then, see if the named commit `<id>` is an ancestor of the tip.  If so, print the branch name.  So if we name commit `U` we get all the branch names, but if we name commit `X` we get just `br1` and `br2`.

Running `git branch --merged [<commit>]` means: for each branch name, look up its tip commit.  (`Z`, `X`, and `X` again.)  Then, see if the tip commit is an ancestor of the commit we just named, or of `HEAD` if we did not name one.  If so, print that branch name.  So if we are sitting on commit `X` right now, we'll see `br1` and `br2`.  However, if we name commit `U`, we get *no* branch names, because `Z` and `X` are not ancestors of `U`.

Running `git branch --no-merged [<commit>]` means: for each branch name, look up its tip commit.  Then, see if the tip commit is an ancestor of the commit we just named, or of `HEAD`.  If *not*, print the branch name.

Again, these are all just simple "is an ancestor" tests, and `git branch` simply runs them for all branch names.  The `--contains`, `--merged`, and `--no-merged` control:

- which commit hashes go on the left and right sides of the ≤ ancestor test; and
- whether a "yes" or "no" result prints the branch-name.

(There's no `--does-not-contain` test to put the argument hash-ID on the left, but print only if the test says "no".  For that, you have to spell out the loop manually.)